# Receber jwt em funções Java

Tags: java, jwt

Bom dia pessoal, estou com a seguinte duvida, eu criei uma função de login em java que valida usuário e senha em uma requisição de login, se o login for bem sucedido ela retorna um jwt, eu pego esse jwt e guardo no meu front-end e o envio para o back-end a cada requisição, como faço agora para receber esse jwt nas minha funções para poder verificar se os usuários realmente estão validados? eu já criei a função que valida o jwt só não estou conseguindo pegar ele quando ele vem no cabeçalho da requisição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa ser criado um filtro de autenticação. Esse filtro será chamado toda vez que uma requisição chegar no seu backend.

```
@Protected
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

private static final String AUTHORIZATION_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

    if(authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(AUTHORIZATION_PREFIX)) {
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("Usuário não logado"); //se não existe o header, lança uma exceção
    }

    String token = authorizationHeader.substring(AUTHORIZATION_PREFIX.length()).trim();

    try {
        //aqui você chamada o seu método de validação
        validateToken(token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //caso não consiga validar, aborte a conexão com um status correspondente ao erro
        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build());
    }
}
```